# List of open-source android launchers

Tags: android, launcher, android-2.3-gingerbread

What actual launchers are open-source? I need launcher for 2.3+, but not launcher-plus or ADW, because they are not supported already. Stock ICS+ launcher is not compilable for 2.3.

Comment: Are you looking for an Open Source `Launcher` because you want to write your own? Why not download the stock Launcher from source and build upon it?

Comment: Yes, I want to write my own, but all the launchers I found are too old, no longer supported, or do not support 2.3 (ICS stock launcher, for example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

according to the list on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_Launchers) , only a few of the launchers are open source.

however  , a launcher is a very simple app . the UI itself is the one that makes the difference.

if you wish to start from scratch , you can test out a demo of a launcher made by google :

http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: This link doesnt have ANY sample of launcher

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer Seems they have changed the website. I've made one in the past too, based on Google's launcher code : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LB-Launcher . If you wish to do the same, try to follow the guidelines there. I hope this can help. Try to clone Google's launcher from here:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3 , and solve all issues it gets you (it has a lot).